# How to correct this indention problem?

Tags: indentation

I use this makro to define a question:

```
\def\bigfreequestion#1\par{#1\par\nobreak
    \begingroup\nobreak
    \advance\leftskip by 1pc
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \par
    \medskip
    \endgroup
    }
```

Then I use it like this:

```
\section{Remarks}
\bigfreequestion What did you like the most? \par \bigskip
\bigfreequestion What didn't you like? \par \bigskip
\bigfreequestion Please share your suggestions how to improve the prototype: \par \bigskip
\bigfreequestion Please share any other remarks: \par
```

But the problem is, the first question is indented correctly:
[image]

Any hints how to correct that?

Comment: As I don't have time to test this, I just post a comment: You could try \def\bigfreequestion#1\par{\noindent #1\par\nobreak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `\def\bigfreequestion#1\par{\noindent #1\par\nobreak`

Note that you can also set the zero indention of the first line of a new paragraph globally by `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`